# NoSuchMethodError is thrown on Google SpeechClient recognize()

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-speech

I am using the Google Speech-To-Text client library to convert some .wav files into text. I have read the documentation and use the sample code to try if it works first. However, I have encountered the NoSuchMethodError method as below.

```
public void Transcribe(String serviceAccountKeyPath) throws Exception {
    CredentialsProvider credentialProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(serviceAccountKeyPath)));
    SpeechSettings settings = SpeechSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(credentialProvider).build();

    try (SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create(settings)) {
        RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.FLAC)
                .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                .build();

        RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setUri("gs://xxx").build();

        RecognizeResponse res = speechClient.recognize(config, audio);
        List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = res.getResultsList();

        for (SpeechRecognitionResult result : results) {
            SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
            System.out.printf("TRANSCRIPTION: %s%n", alternative.getTranscript());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Following is the error trace when it executed **recognize()**:

```
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.opencensus.tags.TagContextBuilder.putPropagating(Lio/opencensus/tags/TagKey;Lio/opencensus/tags/TagValue;)Lio/opencensus/tags/TagContextBuilder;
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1250)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1243)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:53)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.recognize(SpeechClient.java:244)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.recognize(SpeechClient.java:208)
```

Comment: How are you importing this library? Most errors like this mean you have two incompatible library versions.

Comment: I simply followed the instructions from the Google documentation by putting the following in my pom.xml file:<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-speech</artifactId>
  <version>1.13.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: As Sam Orozco already said, that looks like an incompatibility between two libraries (as the method `putPropagating(...)` is not used in your code). So please edit your question to show all the dependencies. Maybe you can find out for yourself, which library of which version by which dependency contains the `io.opencensus.tags.TagContextBuilder` class.

Comment: @howlger Thanks for the advice. By further investigating the dependencies, it seems that my OpenCensus library is old. I could not update the dependency at the moment, but I created a fresh new project using the latest version of the library. Probably such method (putPropagating) does not exist in the older one.

Comment: @SamOrozco Also thanks Sam for the guidance!

Comment: @SamOrozco Do you like to answer the question?